# Edit website text and save to browser?

Tags: google-chrome, console, web, save, edit

I would love to know how to edit website data such as texts...
I know that you can easily do this by using the developer tools in Chrome but the problem is that after you have done a change to the website using that tool... It moves away after a simple refresh :(
So my question is:
How can I make a change to a website and "save" it to the browser so that every time I come back to that specific site, the browser shows the site as it is according to the changed code I made using the developer tools(or similar). You could save it locally yes.. but I want the browser to show the URL as if I actually was on that specific website.

Thank you so much!
Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use chrome extension content-script for this.

### Short guide to create your first extension with content-script

1. Create folder `My extension`, join to it
2. Create `manifest.json`:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "My First Extension",
       "description": "This is my first content-script extension",
       "version": "1.0",
       "content_scripts": [{
           "run_at": "document_end",
           "matches": [
               "https://site_you_want_to_change.com"
           ],
           "js": ["jquery.min.js", "content-script-1.js"]
       }],
       "browser_action": {
       },
       "permissions": [
           "activeTab",
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Create `content-script-1.js` with some script as you execute in your devtools, ex.:

   ```
   // with jQuery - change page background style
   $("body").css({"background-color":"red"});

   // ...or without it - change google country name to 'blablabla'
   document.querySelector(".logo-subtext").innerHTML = "blablabla";

   // ... or replace all text, found on page from 'Country' to 'blablabla'
   allNodes=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
   for(node in allNodes){
     if(allNodes[node].innerHTML != undefined)
     {
       allNodes[node].innerHTML=allNodes[node].innerHTML.replace('Country', 'blablabla');
     }
   }
   ```
4. Put `jquery.min.js` near your `manifest.json` (you may download it from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js)
5. Load your new extension script to your browser: settings -> extensions -> [x] Developer Mode -> Load unpacked extension -> Select "My Extension" folder -> Load

### Read more

Chrome extension quick start guide: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: But I want to edit the content not the style.. Like on google.com so that it says something like "blabla" instead of your country name?

Comment: And btw it seems to work the way that I want it to but still just want to edit some of the elements like labels instead of background color. Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, you may use any javascript code to change anything inside the page dom. Added example to change country name on google.com to blablabla :)

Comment: Like I want to change this <li class="numbers vx_small-text enforceLtr">0,00</li> to 100 every time I open the page... How can I do that using js? Thanks!! Just saw your update.. Looking at it

Comment: You can do it by jquery: `$('li:contains("0,00").numbers.vx_small-text.enforceLtr').text(100);`

Comment: Nice to see that you have added that many examples! but when i use this: "allNodes=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(node in allNodes){
  if(allNodes[node].innerHTML != undefined)
  {
    allNodes[node].innerHTML=allNodes[node].innerHTML.replace('AU', 'asd');
  }" nothing works :(

Comment: Lost } in example.

Comment: I tried changing to background on google to red with your example code abd added the last example code a few lines under it... then the background did not change or the text

Comment: You are the best! Literally

Comment: Glad to help you! :) Now it works as you want?

Comment: EXACTLY how i want it!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript which would be loaded every time when you refresh the page, you can achieve that using a Google Chrome's extension and then change the content using JS.

Remember: all of that is web browser's side and only visible to you.

Comment: I know that it would only be visible to me but how am I supposed to do all that? Like what extension and how can I get the edited html to be loaded using javascript? Thanks!

Comment: If it isa popular site there may be one out there, if not, you would need to write your own JS script to do things that you want.

Comment: I just do not see how I should be able to access elements on the site like a label using js?

Answer (score 0):

1. DevTools has a way to save or "persist" changes, by saving a file to your work space. See here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3
2. You can make a Chrome Extension that uses DOM to read the content, then cache it, and next time the website opens it clears the page and inserts the cached HTML.